# Monit exec not working

Tags: node.js, monit, forever

This is my applicable monit.conf

```
check file feedabilityLog with path /var/www/scraper/feedability/feedabilityLog.txt
if timestamp > 20 seconds then
  exec "/usr/local/bin/forever restart feedability.js"
group feedabilityLog
```

In my monit log file, I get the following:
    error    : 'feedabilityLog' timestamp test failed for /var/www/scraper/feedability/feedabilityLog.txt

which seems to signal that the timestamp check is working. However, monit the exec portion of the script does not work. I even tried putting the restart in a bash file, but that doesn't restart the forever process. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. Figured it out. Absolute paths for EVERYTHING!